# Is it possible to display contact pick list based on account pick list selection?

Tags: visualforce, trigger, picklist, dependent-picklist

An account have a pick list field called `country` and its values with `India, USA, Japan and Russia`. A contact have a pick list field called `state` and values with `Indi1, Indi2, USA1, USA2, Japan1, Japan2, Russia1 and Russia2`.

Create a account with country is India. Now, If we are trying to create a contact with respect to the same account id (where country is India), then contact field should display values with India1 and India2 in edit layout and vice versa.

Any type of solution is acceptable(like declarative/programmatic).

Comment: can be done using programmatic. Give it a try

Comment: @Rohit Mourya, Can we made it without apex code?. If it is possible by  apex code, can you please tell me which concept is possible?